# Using CSV as source to copy files

Tags: command-line, powershell, file-transfer, csv

I have a CSV file (semicolon-separated, actually) in Windows,
with column header info. 
One of the columns contains a partial filename;
it's a filename without path or extension. 
I've been trying to create a PowerShell or Robocopy script
that reads that column and copies all files listed in that column
from a shared folder to a local folder,
but I cannot get it to work.

So here's what the input file looks like

```
COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5
```

`COL2` contains filename without extension.

All the needed files are located somewhere
on file server `\\server\share\folder\` or `\\server\share\folder\subfolder`
– I don't know the exact source directory.

Can I create a PowerShell or Robocopy script that reads the `COL2`,
adds `.pdf` as an extension and copies files to my local drive,
like `C:\temp\dest`, etc?

I've been trying to get this to work like this:

```
$VT = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\test.csv" -Delimiter ";" | ForEach {
copy-item -Path C:\test\source\subfolder1\$($_.COL2)*.* -Recurse -Destination C:\test\dest
copy-item -Path C:\test\source\subfolder2\$($_.COL2)*.* -Recurse -Destination C:\test\dest
copy-item -Path C:\test\source\subfolder3\$($_.COL2)*.* -Recurse -Destination C:\test\dest
copy-item -Path C:\test\source\subfolder4\$($_.COL2)*.* -Recurse -Destination C:\test\dest
}
```

But I'd like the code be more simple and not with all those subfolders in the script. 
I did not manage to get that recurse option to work with `Copy-Item`. 
I'm guessing I'll need to use `Get-ChildItem` here, but what I've been trying script simply copies everything from source to destination or executes and does nothing.

I've just been testing this locally so therefore there's no need to use server folders yet.

Comment: Yes.  It's pretty straightforward.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
Import-Csv myfile.csv -header "Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4;Col5" | % {
    Copy-Item servername:\server\share\$_.pdf C:\temp\
    }
```

I have made several assumptions about what you are trying to do.

1. Your local culture has been set tosome european culture such that csv expects semicolon rather than comma.
2. There is no header in the csv file.
3. The partial filename contains all of the subfolder info needed to locate the file to be copied.
4. You are trying to put all the items into subfolders og the temp folder.

If these assumptions are wrong,  you'll have to rewrite.

Comment: 1) You are correct, delimiter is semicolon  2) There are headers in CSV, but there are so many that I did not list those here  3) Partial filename contains only filename, I'll need to use some recursive search to get all the files  4) Yes, I'd like to put all the files to temp or similiar folder

Comment: Copy-Item has a -recurse feature where it will go through the subfolder tree of a source folder.

Comment: I gave you the wrong syntax for obtaining the files from a server.  you can visit help copy-item to find out how to set up a remote session and use the -Fromsession parameter to obtain files from the remote directory tree.

Comment: I did not mange to get copy-item with recurse option to work. I put the script to starting post. I believe there's more simple way to do this but that's only one that I've been able to do what I want. Maybe somekind of Get-ChildItem would work but I've not yet found a way to do that, tried with different -Filter options

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question, it seems you want something like this:

```
$sourcePath  = '\\server\share\folder'
$destination = 'C:\temp\dest'

# make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

# import the data, and get an string array from COL2 from it
# make sure there are no duplicates in this aray and lop through the filenames
(Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\test.csv" -Delimiter ";").COL2 | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $fileName = '{0}.pdf' -f $_
    # try and find this file somewhere in the source path including its subfolders
    $original = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter $fileName -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($original) {
        $original | Copy-Item -Destination 
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$FileName' could not be found"
    }
}
```